# Resource is not available

Tags: xml, jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I looked different links and sites but couldn't solve the problem of not availabilty of resources. I go through previous stackoverflow answers but couldn't solve. I am using Intellij 2016.2.2

Here is my HelloWorld Example for Spring MVC.

Controller class:

```
package com.himal;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * Created by Himal Acharya on 2016-09-17.
 */
@Controller
public class HelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/hi")

    public ModelAndView helloWorld(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("Hello");
        modelAndView.addObject("message","Hello and Hi");
        return modelAndView;

    }
}
```

I have put spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml and web.xml in WEB-INF.

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>SpringHelloWorldDemo12</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.himal"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property></bean>
</beans>
```

I have put my JSP file under WEB/pages.

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: Himal Acharya
  Date: 2016-09-17
  Time: 3:49 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My project structure in Intellij is as :

[image]

But everytime when run http://localhost:8888/hi .It generates following error:

**The requested resource is not available.**

I spend whole day but couldn't figure out.

Comment: Do you deploy the application as the root web application? Otherwise, it's probably at `http://localhost:8888/SpringHelloWorldDemo12/hi`.

Comment: I haven't deployed as root web application . But i tried http://localhost:8888/SpringHelloWorldDemo12/hi ..Same problem occured

Comment: And... what is the context path you chose to deploy the app to, then?

Comment: I am little confused. I want to run the file /hi

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. How do you deploy your app?

Comment: I am new to Java Advanced . So my answer may not be correct. While I complete the coding, I go To Tomcat 8.0.27 icon and click torun the server. At the run console, it sgows deploying directory is : C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\webapps\manager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123593/discussion-between-himal-acharya-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue by adding context-param in web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
                 version="3.1">
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
            <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </context-param>
            <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
            </listener>
        </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should see in your web.xml for application name

```
<display-name>mvc-test</display-name>
```

may be your request path like bellow
http://localhost:8888/mvc-test/hi

try to change bellow code

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

try to add another xml file in your app like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="main.java.com.core.controller"></context:component-scan>
```

and add path of that file in your web.xml file like bellow

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    classpath:main/resources/config/xmlfilename.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: what is your application name <dispaly-name> tag in web.xml?

Comment: <display-name>mvc-test</display-name>

Comment: I have no transaction with database.Isn't tx for dataabase transcation? I have no idea on adding tx..Any idea?

Comment: Same problem occur. I put before ending of webapp in web.xml as  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath: WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: i told you to create new xml file and don't channge spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml file, you should set the path of your new xml file.

Comment: can you see any jsp files of your app in browser, such as index.jsp?

Comment: I couldn't figure out. Same problem always. No any jsp file opens.

Comment: right click on the jsp file and click run as > run on the server and test to work and show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123605/discussion-between-himal-acharya-and-ali-reza).